How can find key while decrypting the ciphertext? (unknown key)
I want to decrypt the following classical Cipher-text without knowing key:
Cq ligss’v vcjandd ujw, wuqjwgausjkq cv ulxucdd zrj mhuouahj lbh nuvl upgoqlm rx mhfmllcyw cqxiueuwaiq kbdjyg ghoahh, xlre jhjmrfuo vuws nr fuwaiqsf vwwuwnv. Sm fqvhj nkjydlm ewwrey lfwuwuvahjds vgjkamwawdlyg, ulbhnryldhbb whdtfhk mdxy fggpmhluuwaiq, hlrlyflcqy yywlblblfa ijip ghoahh tuqccqy nushvswwaiqk uqv ghvcfsf uwwrjxv li sjcysnh uiqnyukuwaiqk. Cw hlrncgwm wzy eswntiqw zrj xdlu lfnhyllls dfx fghiaxhfnlsflls, hfmxjcqy nksn rffb ahwwhgwx uwwlhchfnv uuq swfwmv kyqkcwaph vuws uqv nksn ll lheulfm xfwkshjwx gmllfa wjuqkglkmlgh. Fjsslijjuszs qgn rffb kuiwaxslgk cqvcyaxxsfv’ hllnufq vxl uoki xfxhjjlfm jdiesf fggpwlfw, mhuouw wregxfcfsnlghv, shg fuwaiqsf vwwxjcwq, gdccqy cw ahgamswhvsvow cq s qrjfg lbdl lhdchk iq vcjandd nummw.

So far I have used different online-tools unsucessfully.
I inspired from this source using Pythonic code to reach:

Plain Text
Finding Key

import argparse

class CaesarAlgorithm:

    def encrypt(self, message, key, alphabet):

        # start with empty ciphertext
        ciphertext = ""

        # iterate through each character in message
        for old_character in message:
            new_character = ""

            # if character is in alphabet -> append to ciphertext
            if(old_character in alphabet):
                index = alphabet.index(old_character)
                new_index = (index + key) % len(alphabet)
                new_character = alphabet[new_index]

            # Note: characters not defined in the alphabet are ignored

            # add new character to ciphertext
            ciphertext = ciphertext + new_character

        # return ciphertext to calling function
        return ciphertext


    def decrypt(self, message, key, alphabet):

        # decrypting is like encrypting but with negative key
        plaintext = self.encrypt(message, 0 - key, alphabet)

        # return plaintext to calling function
        return plaintext


# parse the arguments (args) given via the command line
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-e", "--encrypt", dest="encrypt_or_decrypt", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--decrypt", dest="encrypt_or_decrypt", action="store_false")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--message", help="message for encrypt / decrypt", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-k", "--key",     help="key for encrypt / decrypt", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--alphabet", help="defined alphabet", type=str)


ciphertext="Cq ligss’v vcjandd ujw, wuqjwgausjkq cv ulxucdd zrj mhuouahj lbh nuvl upgoqlm rx mhfmllcyw cqxiueuwaiq kbdjyg ghoahh, xlre jhjmrfuo vuws nr fuwaiqsf vwwuwnv. Sm fqvhj nkjydlm ewwrey lfwuwuvahjds vgjkamwawdlyg, ulbhnryldhbb whdtfhk mdxy fggpmhluuwaiq, hlrlyflcqy yywlblblfa ijip ghoahh tuqccqy nushvswwaiqk uqv ghvcfsf uwwrjxv li sjcysnh uiqnyukuwaiqk. Cw hlrncgwm wzy eswntiqw zrj xdlu lfnhyllls dfx fghiaxhfnlsflls, hfmxjcqy nksn rffb ahwwhgwx uwwlhchfnv uuq swfwmv kyqkcwaph vuws uqv nksn ll lheulfm xfwkshjwx gmllfa wjuqkglkmlgh. Fjsslijjuszs qgn rffb kuiwaxslgk cqvcyaxxsfv’ hllnufq vxl uoki xfxhjjlfm jdiesf fggpwlfw, mhuouw wregxfcfsnlghv, shg fuwaiqsf vwwxjcwq, gdccqy cw ahgamswhvsvow cq s qrjfg lbdl lhdchk iq vcjandd nummw."

# Simulate command-line arguments
# Replace with your desired values
args = parser.parse_args(["-d", "-m", ciphertext, "-k", "3", "-a", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"])  

# create caesar instance
caesar = CaesarAlgorithm()

# if --encrypt -> call encrypt function
if(args.encrypt_or_decrypt == True):
    print(caesar.encrypt(args.message, args.key, args.alphabet))

# if --decrypt -> call decrypt function
else:
    print(caesar.decrypt(args.message, args.key, args.alphabet))

So far, I could not achieve Plain Text and find the identified key
Even I have tried to use the following online tools and find the key mannually but I could not yet:

https://cryptii.com/pipes/caesar-cipher
https://ciphereditor.com/explore/caesar-cipher
https://www.dcode.fr/caesar-cipher


The key is UDS. Text starts with "In today’s digital age, cryptography is crucial for securing ...".

Your encoded text does not appear to be encoded with a Ceasar Cipher. Therefore, trying to use a Ceasar Cipher to decode it will not work.

This code does not analyze the ciphertext and deduce the key, which is what I thought you wanted.  I don't understand how you thought it would work.

@0stone0 How you come up with identified Key? which tools have you used?

@JohnGordon How can improve this pythonic code to identify the used Key and decrypt the Cipher-text? any idea?

It is a Vigenere Cipher - https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/vigenere-cipher

I've used this @Mario: https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher

@MT0 I have used it before but get error: see this screenshot

@0stone0 Yes this after selecting Vigenere Cryptanalysis (Kasiski's Test) and push the automatic decrypt botton can find the key: UDS and then use again option knowing key uisng select "Knowing the Key/Password" and it could decrypt the cipher text into plain text using this online tools. I have to confess that I tried before but I could not see if UDS is key I looking for in left side.

If the ciphertext were actually encrypted with a caesar cipher (which it apparently wasn't, but that is a separate issue), you could just try all possible keys from 1 to 25 and see which one of them produces a readable plaintext.

To hammer in the point, you can't automatically reliably decode even a simple cypher like Caesar without making use of a dictionary. Staistical analysis (letter frequencies in the target language) can be used though for long enough messages.

@Swifty can one improve this pythonic code to extract key and then decrypt the cipher text into plain text?

As I said, even for a simple substitution cypher (Caesar being an example) it's not that simple. And for Vigenere it's even more complicated: from what I remember, you have to do statistical analysis on groups of letters based on the presumed length of the key to guess the key, then use a dictionary to confirm it.

can one improve this pythonic code Yes, you can.  We're not going to do it for you.

@Swifty I see your point and thanks for sharing your input.

What you can do for actual Caesar code is write code that prints the 25 possible decryptions. Then use your eyes/brain to find out which is the correct one :)

@JohnGordon actually I was wondering if there elegant way using some open-source packages to solve the problem not developing new codes.

@Swifty yeah let me see if I could manage it to extend the code to reach what you pointed.

Your cipher text is not encoded with a Caesar Cipher, it is encoded with a Vigenere Cipher with the key uds.

You can write a Vigenere Cipher:
class VigenereCipher:
    @staticmethod
    def _key_iter(key):
        while True:
            for ch in key:
                yield ch

    @staticmethod
    def _lookup_table(key, alphabet):
        if any(ch not in alphabet for ch in key):
            raise ValueError("Key should be in the alphabet")
        return {
            ch: alphabet[alphabet.index(ch):] + alphabet[:alphabet.index(ch)]
            for ch in key
        }
        
    @staticmethod
    def encode(message, key, alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
        lookup = VigenereCipher._lookup_table(key, alphabet)
        key_iter = VigenereCipher._key_iter(key)
        return "".join(
            lookup[next(key_iter)][alphabet.index(ch)]
            if ch in alphabet else ch
            for ch in message
        )

    @staticmethod
    def decode(message, key, alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
        lookup = VigenereCipher._lookup_table(key, alphabet)
        key_iter = VigenereCipher._key_iter(key)
        return "".join(
            alphabet[lookup[next(key_iter)].index(ch)]
            if ch in alphabet else ch
            for ch in message
        )

Then if you know the key (and alphabet), you can decode the string:
ciphertext="Cq ligss’v vcjandd ujw, wuqjwgausjkq cv ulxucdd zrj mhuouahj"
print(VigenereCipher.decode(ciphertext.lower(), "uds"))

Which outputs:
in today’s digital age, cryptography is crucial for securing


If you want to find an unknown key then you will have to:

Generate all possible combinations of keys.
Decode the text using the key.
Perform some sort of analysis on the text to see if it makes sense.

For example, if you know the key is length 3 and has no repeated characters then you can generate potential solutions using:
from itertools import permutations

common_two_letter_words = ("as", "to", "be", "in", "by", "is", "it", "at", "of", "or", "on", "an", "us", "if", "my", "do", "no", "he", "up", "so", "am", "me", "go", "hi")

def has_vowel(word):
    return any(vowel in word for vowel in "aeiouy")

for key in permutations(alphabet, 3):
    output = VigenereCipher.decode(ciphertext.lower(), key)
    if (
        output[:2] in common_two_letter_words
        and output[9] == "s"
        and all(has_vowel(word) for word in output.split(" "))
        and output[37:39] in common_two_letter_words
    ):
        print("".join(key), output)

Which looks to see if the input decodes the two-letter words to common words and that the character after the apostrophe is an s and that each word contains at least one vowel and outputs:
cdo an xgdeq’s hagmlap sgi, urchtsyrehhc as gjugaap xov kegmrmfg
cds an tgdaq’s dagilal sge, uryhtoyrahhy as cjucaal xor kecmrifg
cdy an ngduq’s xagclaf sgy, urshtiyruhhs as wjuwaaf xol kewmrcfg
udc in jodqy’s tigytab agu, croptegrqpho is srusiab foh sesuryng
ude in hodoy’s rigwtaz ags, crmptcgrophm is qruqiaz fof sequrwng
udg in fodmy’s pigutax agq, crkptagrmphk is oruoiax fod seourung
udi in dodky’s nigstav ago, criptygrkphi is mrumiav fob semursng
udk in bodiy’s ligqtat agm, crgptwgriphg is krukiat foz sekurqng
udm in zodgy’s jigotar agk, creptugrgphe is iruiiar fox seiurong
udo in xodey’s higmtap agi, crcptsgrephc is grugiap fov segurmng
udq in vodcy’s figktan agg, craptqgrcpha is erueian fot seeurkng
uds in today’s digital age, cryptography is crucial for securing
udw in podwy’s zigetah aga, cruptkgrwphu is yruyiah fon seyureng
udy in noduy’s xigctaf agy, crsptigruphs is wruwiaf fol sewurcng

The correct solution is in there and the other solutions are gibberish. With more analysis (and a dictionary of more and longer words) you can narrow down the solution to the correct key. That is left as an exercise for the reader.
fiddle

Oh thanks for providing answer (+1). as @Swifty  pointed one needs to use the eyes/brain to find out which key is the correct one :)

Indeed, or expand on the common_two_letter_words principle by including a dictionary of common words. Furthermore, this requires you to guess the key's length (note that so do the online Vigenere tools).
